# javascript promise: a problem with setTimeout inside a promise race

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

the following code outputs (1) then (3) whitch is wrong .. why?

the following code is intended to wait 3 seconds and print (3) then wait another 1 second then print (1)
so the correct order must be (3) then (1)

I guess the problem is wait() returns a new promise, but how can I fix this issue
note: all functions must return 'this' for chaining

```js
class test extends Promise {
  constructor(fn) {
    super(fn)
    return this
  }

  wait(seconds) {
    return new test(resolve =>
      setTimeout(function() {
        resolve(seconds)
      }, seconds * 1000)
    )
  }

  done(fn) {
    return super.then(fn)
  }
}

p = new test(r => r())
p.wait(3) //(2) must be before (1)
  .done(x => console.log(x))
  .wait(1)
  .done(x => console.log(x))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `wait` to call `.then` *on the current `test` object* (that is, `this`), and return the constructed `Promise` chain:

```js
class test extends Promise {
  constructor(fn) {
    super(fn)
    return this
  }

  wait(seconds) {
    return this.then(() => new test(resolve => {
      setTimeout(function() {
        resolve(seconds)
      }, seconds * 1000);
    }))
  }

  done(fn) {
    return super.then(fn)
  }
}

console.log('start');
p = new test(r => r())
p.wait(3) //(2) must be before (1)
  .done(x => console.log(x))
  .wait(1)
  .done(x => console.log(x))
```

Comment: I suppose it should be `this.then` instead of `super.then`, also unclear what's the purpose of `done` since it's same thing as `then`.

Comment: worked! ..thank you @CertainPerformance , you also guide me to a good lesson that I have to use .then() to wait for the previous function in the chain

Comment: I have a method this.then() with a different signature witch calls super.then(), if I used this.then() inside it, it will lead to infinite loop , do you have another idea? 
@estus

Comment: @xxyy This isn't shown in the question, so it depends. It's not evident that you need to extend Promise at all since your class doesn't use promise API but its own. You could make use of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance and use promises internally.

Comment: class myPromise extends Promise{
 then(success,fail,otherArgument){
 if(otherArgument)doSomething()
return this.then(success,fail)
}
}